# cy.origin is not a function error displayed

Tags: cypress, cypress-origin

I am trying to use the new origin function and I got this error:

> No commands were issued in this test.
>
> **TypeError**
> The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
> `cy.origin is not a function`

The code is really basic:

```js
cy.origin('https://www.acme.com', () => {
    cy.visit('/history/founder')
    cy.get('h1').contains('About our Founder, Marvin Acme')
})
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Two things to check

- have you added `experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true` to `cypress.json`?
- are you using Cypres v9.6.0+